# User Input EMA and Cross

Tags: pine-script

I want to build a script that allows the user to input 5 different EMAs and plot a cross on the chart when any of the EMAs overlap one another. Give the user an ability to select/unselect a cross over any 5 EMAS.
For example: EMAs entered are 5,9,13,50,200. Then it will allow user to select if he wants to see cross between 5 and 9, 5 and 13, 5 and 50, 5 and 200 and so on and so forth. The below script does between 5 and 13, but doesn't have an ability to select/unselect if cross should appear or not.

```
  //@version=3
study(title="EMA Cross 5/13", overlay=true)
short = ema(close, 5)
long = ema(close, 13)
plot(short, color = red)
plot(long, color = blue)
plot(cross(short, long) ? short : na, style = cross, linewidth = 4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study(title="Help (EMA Cross)", overlay=true)
sl = input(defval=5,    title="Short length", type=input.integer, options=[5, 9, 13, 50, 200])
ll = input(defval=13,   title="Long length",  type=input.integer, options=[5, 9, 13, 50, 200])
cr = input(defval=true, title="Show cross",   type=input.bool)

short = ema(close, sl)
long  = ema(close, ll)
plot(short, color = color.red)
plot(long, color = color.blue)
plot(cross(short, long) and cr ? short : na, style = plot.style_cross, linewidth = 4)
```